# Second Cohomology of the modular group

Tags: abstract-algebra, homology-cohomology, group-cohomology

What is known about $H^2(SL(2,\mathbb{Z}),\mathbb{Z})$? 
Anyone knows some references about that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is known, see the first lines [here](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00443899/document): "Our goal is to compute its cohomology groups with trivial coefficients, i.e. $H^q (SL_N(\mathbb{Z}),\mathbb{Z})$. The case $N = 2$ is well-known and follows from the fact that $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ is the amalgamated product of two finite cyclic groups ([21], [6], II.7, Ex.3, p.52). Here $[21]$ is Serre's book *Trees*.

I found the result also in Richard Hain's paper [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0812.1803.pdf), Proposition $3.13$, with proof (page $25-26$).
$$
H^r(SL_2(\mathbb{Z}),\mathbb{Z})\cong \begin{cases} \mathbb{Z}/12, \text{ if $r$ is even} \\
0, \text{otherwise} \end{cases}
$$

Comment: Thanks. That's exactly what I found too... In [6] (that's Brown's book about Cohomology of groups) it seems to be that this exercise is for homology?
I had a quick look into Serre's book but couldn't find the section. Do you know where I have to look? And do you know the answer for my question?

Comment: Yes, I know the answer, and found a proof online in an arxiv paper ($80$ pages!) by Richard Hain.